# Dos formas por una función: "ser+participio" y "se pasiva" para referirse a algo en voz pasiva

Tags: cópulas, voz-pasiva, participio

Mis preguntas son algo básicas y generales:

1. ¿Cuáles son los factores estilísticos y/o dialectales que inciden en la elección de "ser + participio" o "se pasiva refleja" para referirse a algo en voz pasiva? Ej. "la  fiesta es celebrada cada año" vs. "la fiesta se celebra cada año".
2. ¿Existe también una diferencia semántica/funcional?

Comment: interesante pregunta... además creo que también aplican diferencias regionales. p.ej "la fiesta es celebrada" es correcto pero yo jamás lo usaría por sobre "la fiesta se celebra"

Comment: Claro, y me parece que eso nos lleva a la parte semántica/funcional. Es decir, me pregunto si hay una clase semántica verbal o nominal que en términos probabilísticos favorece el uso de una forma en particular. ¿Habrá un motivo que explique por qué el verbo "celebrar" y/o el sustantivo "la fiesta" te suena más natural/aceptable con se pasiva refleja?

Comment: Supongo que la pasiva, al ser más inusual, hace hincapié en la forma verbal (que es en lo que se diferencia de la pasiva refleja), es decir, "fue celebrado" resalta el tiempo verbal pasado y que se concluyó; frente a la pasiva refleja que resalta más el sujeto paciente y otras informaciones.

Comment: Es cierto, pero cambiaste el tinte de la pregunta al dar el ejempo de "ser + participio" en tiempo pasado. Supongamos que ambas construcciones están en tiempo presente (o sea, que los demás factores permanecen igual).

Answer (score 3):

Algunas diferencias:

- La pasiva con "se" es más idiomática que la pasiva perifrástica (ser + participio): "La fiesta se celebra cada año" es más común que "La fiesta es celebrada cada año", que suena más pesada.
- Sólo la pasiva perifrástica permite la presencia de un agente y, cuando el agente es requerido, esa forma de la pasiva resulta ser la única posible: "La fiesta es celebrada por las familias fundadoras cada año".
- La pasiva con "se" permite mayor flexibilidad en el orden sintáctico y esto ofrece una mayor versatilidad estilística: "Cada año se celebra la fiesta en un lugar diferente" (NO "Cada año es celebrada la fiesta en un lugar diferente").
- En textos técnicos y científicos suele preferirse la pasiva perifrástica porque, aunque el agente esté ausente, da a entender que la acción es llevada a cabo por alguien. Así, en ese tipo de textos es más habitual encontrar "La mezcla es colocada en un recipiente" que "La mezcla se coloca en un recipiente".

Answer (score 0):

En general estoy muy de acuerdo con Gustavson, pero quiero insistir en el segundo punto:

> Sólo la pasiva perifrástica permite la presencia de un agente y,
>   cuando el agente es requerido, esa forma de la pasiva resulta ser la
>   única posible: "La fiesta es celebrada por las familias fundadoras
>   cada año".

En mi caso, yo creo que sólo utilizo la forma "ser + participio" cuando necesito indicar o más bien **resaltar** el agente. Si éste está implícito u omitido, uso la pasiva refleja. No es que "ser + participio" esté mal, pero la pasiva refleja da lugar a una expresión mucho más fluida, flexible e idiomática.